# django unknown column after migrations

Tags: django

I have a weird problem. I've added the below to the model. I have run migrations, but I still still get the error no such column: Linked_OKR

```
linked_OKR = models.ForeignKey(okrtasks, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='okrid', blank=True, null=True)
```

Weirdly in the admin view, it also shows up not in bold, unlike all other columns

Any idea what's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have used:

```
db_column='okrid', blank=True, null=True
```

`db_column='okrid'`: This signifies that that model will use `okrid` as the column name and not `linked_OKR`.

`blank=True, null=True`: This signifies that the field is optional and can accept blank and null values. Django admin does not bold this field since bold means required fields.